# Amazon S3 CORS error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I've been getting permission denied errors when my app requests files through Javascript on amazon S3.

I have a CORS file set up and it seems to work most of the time, but fail intermittently.

I can always solve this problem by clearing my browser cache.

Any clues on what this could be? I'm not using cloudfront, which I know some people have found to cause a problem.

Comment: Can you post sample code that is failing intermittently? Or, example requests and responses?

Comment: Also your bucket policy?

Comment: Rejection: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://s3.amazonaws.com/rifff_bucket/uploads%2F20130313T2336Z_5a9d96ef0d43ef775b9781cd336e1eb2%2Fsnarelayer.mp3. Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Bucket Policy: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>

    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>

Comment: Sorry - Can't see how to format these better - any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I have the same problem (not a localhost issue).

Comment: I seem to remember feeling that incognito mode solved it, and that no one apart from me experienced it - but that is only a very vague recollection.

Answer (score -5):

As far as I remember, Chrome does not allow CORS requests made from localhost:

> Rejection: XMLHttpRequest cannot load s3.amazonaws.com/rifff_bucket/….
>   Origin localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Try to setup a dev domain on your work PC.

Other then that, for me S3 also rejects CORS requests even though they aren't made from local host.